# Performance issue for batch insertion into marklogic

Tags: performance, insert, document, marklogic

I have the requirement to insert 10,000 docs into marklogic in less than 10 seconds.

I tested in one single-node marklogic server in the following way:

1. use `xdmp:spawn` to pass the doc insertion task to task server;
2. use `xdmp:document-insert` without specify forest explicitly;
3. the task server has 8 theads to process tasks;
4. We have enabled `CPF`.

The performance is very bad: it took 2 minutes to finish the 10,000 doc creation.
I'm sure the performance will be better if I tested it in a cluster environment, but I'm not sure whether it can finish in less than 10 seconds.

Please advise the way of improving the performance.

Comment: If you are only doing insertions, then disk subsystem IO will very likely your limiting factor. If ML Monitoring Dashboard (under Rates and Loads) shows high load, then disk/IO in your test environment is maxed out, and there's not much you can do other than provision your test environment to be more similar to your production environment. Also, ML recommends having 6 forests configured. That could have some impact on insert performance as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the data you try to process, and the ingestion process? Why did you use spawn in the first place, and why did you enable CPF? Note that enabling CPF, enables triggers, which also slows down inserts..

Answer (score 1):

I would start by gathering more information. What version of MarkLogic is this? What OS is it running on? What's the CPU? RAM? What's the storage subsystem? How many forests are attached to the database?

Then gather OS-level metrics, to see if one of the subsystems is an obvious bottleneck. For now I won't speculate beyond that.

Comment: It's a **VM** env: 1. Marklogic 6 2. Linux 2.6.18-348.18.1.el5 3. cpu: 2 processors, model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 4. RAM: 4G 5. storage: local disk 6. forest: 1 7. OS metrics: do you mean check the OS I/O when running test? such as iostat

Comment: Monitor the activity of all subsystems under load: CPU, RAM, disk, network. For CPU and disk, `iostat -mxz 5` is a good place to start. Drop the `z` if your iostat doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a fast load, I wouldn't use xdmp:spawn for each individual document, nor use CPF. But 2 minutes for 10k docs doesn't necessarily sound slow. On the other hand, I have reached up to 3k/sec, but without range indexes, transforms, whatsoever. And a very fast disk (e.g. ssd)..

HTH!

Comment: 1. I need it finish in 10 seconds. 2. I don't have SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2 socket server, 128GB-256GB of ram, fast IO (400-800MB/sec sustained)

- Appropriate number of forests (12 primary or 6 primary/6 secondary)
- More than 8 threads assuming enough cores
- CPF off

Turn on perf history, look in metrics, and you will see where the bottleneck is.

SSD is not required - just IO throughput...which multiple spinning disks provide without issue.

Comment: I tested in a VM machine #1 RAM: 4G #2 cpu: 2 processors whose model name "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650" http://ark.intel.com/products/47922/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5650-(12M-Cache-2_66-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI) #3 IO: how to check the IO capability? I can get the I/O by using iostat command, it seems it's writing at 2 MB/s. #4 Forest number: only 1. It seems I have only two processors, and I only have one forest. #5 CPF: I'll not use task server, so that CPF will not affect document insertion.